# Error when calling c++ dll from delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, fortran

I am trying to use create a c++ wrapper (using MSVS2013) for some fortran code. The wrapper is supposed to be called from DELPHI (old code created in DELPHI 5 - which I cannot touch). (DELPHI -> C++ dll -> fortran dll)
The aim is that some data `struct`s (`record`in delphi) with `int`'s and `double`'s and `double[]`'s are passed from delphi to fortran for calculations.
The c++ dll -> fortran is no problem - that I have tested with another c++ executable. It works. The problem is when delphi calls c++ and c++ calls fortran. Then I get an error that says

> Project "myDelphiProject.exe" raised exception class EZeroDivide with message 'Floating point division by zero'.

There is no problem calling the c++ wrapper if the call to fortran does not happen.
I have tested and confirmed that all variables get through between delphi and c++. Calling convention is set to `cdecl`.

Simplified code:
Delphi

```
interface
rec1 = record
  var1,var2: double;
  end;
procedure myCppWrap(record1: myrecord); cdecl; external 'mycppwrap.dll' name '_myCppWrap'
implementation
procedure MyDelphiFunc();
var
 ...
begin
 myCppWrap(rec1)
 ...
```

Simplified c++ code:

```
struct rec1
{
  double var1,var2;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl myCppWrap(rec1 r1);
extern "C" *myFortranSub(double *varF1,double *varF2);
```

In short: 
DELPHI -> C++ works, C++ -> Fortran works, DELPHI -> C++ -> Fortran does not work.

Does anyone have any idea of what is wrong?

---

EDIT:
OK.. so I have managed to narrow it down:
I have division by zero that results in infinity (which is a correct internal result with the given input - this is not direct output from fortran dll).
This goes well when being called by c++ but not from  delphi when the fortran dll is compiled using default release settings.
However it does work when using debug settings, both in c++ and delphi.
I output variables to a text  file (before and after division) for verification and in all 4 cases the divisor is 0 and the result is 'inf' in the three cases that goes well. Both in debug and release mode I have the same setting for floating point exception handling "Produce NaN, signed infinities, and denormal results".

This turns out to be more of a compiler setting/flag problem than coding...

Anyone have any experience with this??
(I am working on a small and verifiable code piece)

Comment: What is wrong is that you have a defect in your code. Unless you actually show a [mcve] we can't see your code. Either do that, or do some debugging yourself. Showing fake code doesn't help at all. Your C++ code is clearly fake. The functions don't have return values declared.

Comment: okidoki.. I am on it :)

Comment: This is because the Delphi runtime unmasks floating point exceptions. If your code is designed to work with then masked, then mask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following [David Heffeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)'s advice... adding

```
use ifcore
```

and

```
fpe_old_flags = FOR_SET_FPE(0)
```

in the beginning of the code solved it. Thanks a lot David!

Comment: Worth a note that this is specific to the Intel Fortran compiler.